# how to make auto slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="sp-content">
    <div class="sp-parallax-bg"></div>
    <ul class="sp-slider bxslider">
        <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($resp)) { ?>
        <li><a href="#slide1"><img src="photo/<?php echo $row['image']?>"></a>
        </li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- sp-content -->
</div>
```

this is the html code for the auto slider.

.css file

```
.sp-slider {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
    -moz-transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
    -o-transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
    -ms-transition: left ease-in 0.8s;
    transition: left ease-in 0.8s; 
}
.sp-slider > li img{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0 50px 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

how do I make auto slider using these as I've tried jquery but still unable to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of JQuery plugins that do these sort of things  - [take a look](http://bfy.tw/2kr9).